# How to combine 3 lists to create a dictionary with one key and two values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i would like to know how I could create a dictionary using the three lists. `coun_keys` to be a key and `months_values` and `cases_values` are to be the values.

I only found sources where I could use the `zip()` function to have a key: `value`, but how can I have key: `value1, value2`?

```
def main(csvfile,country ,type ):
    with open(csvfile,"r") as file:
        if type.lower() == "statistics ":
            coun_keys = []
            months_values = []
            cases_values = []
            listname =[]
            coun_month={}

            for line in file:
                columns = (line.strip().split(","))
                listname.append(columns)

            listname.pop(0)

            for line in listname:
               date1 = line[3].split("/")
               coun_keys.append(str(line[2]))
               months_values.append(int(date1[1]))
               cases_values.append(int(line[4]))
```

Comment: Please share an example with input and expected output

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean, like:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = 'abc'
list3 = [5, 6, 7]

print(dict(zip(list1,zip(list2, list3))))
```

#############################

For your code specifically, I would break up what you want to do into pieces. First define what you want to do with each line of your file:

```
def process_line(line):
    line  = line.strip().split(',')
    date1 = line[3].split("/")
    key   = str(line[2])
    month = int(date1[1])
    case  = int(line[4])
    return key,(month,case)
```

Notice I group the values I want in a tuple, in particular, I want the process_line function to return my "key" and my "value" (a pair). Now open your file and process the lines:

```
f = open(csvfile)
next(f) #Skip the first line
result = dict(process_line(line) for line in f)
f.close()
```

Comment: hmmm. how can i implement that in my code? like cause coun_keys are a list of string values. months_values  and  cases_values  are a list of integer values. so i want string key list: int value 1 list, int value 2 list

Answer (score 0):

This might help...

`newDict = dict(zip(coun_keys, [months_values, cases_values]))`

Comment: i removed count_ month = {} and put the line of code you provided but sadly when i use print statement it shows to be an empty dictionary

Comment: It's a little hard to tell where the issue is coming from. It might help if you provide more details about the data you are using. There might be an issue with the lists you created. Check if they are created correctly first. Then you can use the line above to create a dictionary out of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're the same length, you can also do:

```
your_dict = {coun_keys[i] : (months_values[i], cases_values[i]) for i in range(len(coun_keys))}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For example,**

```
lst1 = [a,b,c,d]
lst2 = [1,2,3,4]
lst3 = [5,6,7,8]

dict1 = dict(zip(lst1,zip(lst2,lst3)))
```

Comment: ```dict1 = dict(zip(coun_keys,zip(months_values,cases_values)))
            print(dict1)```

Comment: thats what i did but dictionary is still being printed as empty. i did this by replacing count_month{} in my code above.